# adb devices not working in Hyper-V

Tags: applications, adb, vm

I connected Motorola android device on my host machine. I can not view the connected device from Hyper-V VM (Windows 10)

I can not see connected android devices (adb) from VM, but i can very well see it on host.

1. Device on developer mode
2. SDK installed in both VM and Host

[image]

Comment: Evaluative suggestions: Does your VM have the proper driver? Clearly the host machine does, if it recognizes the device. Does the VM use pass-thru for host recognized devices?

Comment: after lot of try i managed to see devices in VM (from host machine USB) using redirector software, because Hyper-V does not have the capabilities. Yes, all drivers were up-to-date. But, i dont want to use redirector software to see devices in VM (Hyper-V), if any alternative solution possible, it would be great.